# In `subprocess` functions, what is the default encoding when `text=True`?

Tags: python, character-encoding, subprocess

In functions like `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.check_output`, the option `text=True` (and its legacy alias `universal_newlines=True`) causes the output to be decoded as text and converted to `str`, instead of returning `bytes`.

I know that you can select a specific output encoding with `encoding=`. But I do not see in the documentation what the *default* encoding is, when using `text=True`.

Where/how is that default encoding set, and can it be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer *is* actually in the docs, albeit a little buried:

> If encoding or errors are specified, or text is true, file objects for stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode using the specified encoding and errors or the `io.TextIOWrapper` default.

Following the link to the docs for `io.TextIOWrapper`, you can see that the default encoding can be found with [`sys.getencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getencoding), which is platform- and locale-dependent.